# Superimpose two textures on an SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, textures, skspritenode

I would like to achieve the effect shown in this gif.

[image: Shiny Sprite]

Currently I do this with a series of ~7 png images with a red background and a white line, these are animated through the sprite with an SKAction.

There are a few others additions I would like to make to the sprite, that can change depending on situation, and also I would like to repeat this with a number of colours.
This results in: 6 colours, 7 shine effects, 5 edge effects and 4 corner effects resulting in 136 combinations of textures I would need to create and store.

I feel like there has to be a way to superimpose png's with transparent backgrounds when setting the texture of a sprite but I cannot seem to find a way to do this anywhere.

Is this possible so that I can reduce the number of assets to 22 or do I have to make all 136 and build in logic to the class to decide which to use?

Comment: Use multiple SKSpriteNodes and colorBlendFactor

Comment: If I were to use this method and add child for the effect how would the performance of the extra sprites weigh against the extra storage of simply creating all the textures? There could be up to 70 base sprites for which these effect are to be added to.

Comment: wouldn't cost much at all, but you would save a ton of memory in the process.  You need 1 sprite for each of your squares, and 1 big sprite for the glare (or multiple sprites compositing of one big glare to save texture memory if need be) Your gray squares have a zPosition of 2, your glare has a zPosition of 1, and your color squares have a zPosition of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted an effect like this for my game, I tried a lot of options. I tried using particles for performance but couldn't even get close. I know you can accomplish it with Shaders, but i didn't go that route and in iOS 12 Shaders won't be support Open GL anyway. In the end I opted to go with CropNodes.

This is my glare image, it is hard to see because it slightly transparent whiteish image.

[image]

This is the results I achieved using CropNodes

[image]

```
class Glare: SKSpriteNode {

    var glare = SKSpriteNode()
    private var cropNode = SKCropNode()

    init(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {

        super.init(texture: nil, color: color, size: size)

        alpha = 0.7
        zPosition = 10

        setupGlare()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupGlare() {

        let buffer: CGFloat = 10

        let mask = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .black, size: self.size)

        let texture = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Sprites").textureNamed("glare")
        glare = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        glare.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - (self.size.width / 2 + buffer), y: self.size.height / 2 + buffer)
        glare.setScale(3.50)
        glare.zPosition = 1

        cropNode.zPosition = 2
        cropNode.maskNode = mask
        cropNode.addChild(glare)

        let random = Double(CGFloat.random(min: 0, max: 1))

        let pause = SKAction.wait(forDuration: random)
        let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: self.size.width + buffer * 2, y: 0 - (self.size.height + buffer * 2), duration: 0.5)
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
        let reset = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0 - (self.size.width + buffer * 2), y: self.size.height + buffer * 2, duration: 0.0)
        let seq = SKAction.sequence([move, wait, reset])
        let repeater = SKAction.repeatForever(seq)
        let repeaterSeq = SKAction.sequence([pause, repeater])

        glare.run(repeaterSeq)
    }

    func showGlare(texture: SKTexture) {

        let mask = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

        cropNode.maskNode = mask
        glare.isHidden = false
        if cropNode.parent == nil { self.addChild(cropNode)}
    }

    func hideGlare() {

        glare.isHidden = true
        //remove cropnode from the node tree
        cropNode.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

and then in my GameScene...

I add my glares to a glare layer but that isn't necessary. I also go through when the game loads and create my glares for all 15 slots ahead of time and put them in an array. This way I do not have to create them on the fly and I can just turn on slot 10 any time I want and turn it off as well.

```
private var glares = [Glare]()

let glare = Glare(color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: kSymbolSize, height: kSymbolSize))
glare.position = CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(x - 1) * kSymbolSize) + (kSymbolSize / 2), y: 0 - (CGFloat(y) * kSymbolSize) + (kSymbolSize / 2))
glare.zPosition = 100
glareLayer.addChild(glare)
glares.append(glare)
```

When I want to show the glare on a slot

> EDIT texture here for you would just be a blank square texture the size of your tile.

```
glares[index].showGlare(texture: symbol.texture!)
```

When I want to hide it

```
glares[index].hideGlare()
```

Comment: Looking at this, you may not need your crop node,  if you did your zPositioning correctly,  you place the disabled grid above the enabled graphics, and place the glare in-between

Comment: true, but I wanted the glare to only appear on the objects themselves, not on the tile at the back. (ie. if the square behind the cherries was red you wouldn't see the highlight on the background it would only sheen the cherries)

Comment: ahh ok, that would make sense then

Comment: but even if I wanted to highlight the whole square, I think you would still have to use the cropnode because the glare would extend past the tile boundaries when moving

Comment: alright, now you lost me lol...  the idea I had was to have the glare extend past the tile boundaries, but the zposition of your disabled/grayed area would be covering the extra glare because it is above it.  but I guess if you had 2 next to each other, it would become a problem (unless you use one mega glare instead of individual glares)

Comment: yes, two tiles beside each other definitely were an issue and the disabled area is transparent so the sheen would still be somewhat visible

Comment: i'm not dismissing your idea. quite the contrary I wasn't crazy about using 15 cropnodes but couldn't find another way. FYI caching the cropnodes gave me very little performance hit on FPS

Comment: Oh that is why I suggested it,  crop nodes should be used sparingly

Comment: Of course in your case, you could also finagle it to where you are only using 1 crop node with multiple shaped holes in it

Comment: It wouldn't be multiple masks, it would be multiple nodes that make 1 huge mask and act as a big cookie cutter.  So if I was doing it with a mask,  I would make sure that your graghics on your slot were all in 1 big parent node,  and just use a copy of that parent node (all 15 nodes get copied in the process) as the mask.

Comment: (O . O) Mind blown! I like that kind of "out of the box" thinking. Thanks